# Unable to print JSON values using for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have JSON values look like this

```
var results=[obj1,obj2,obj3];
```

and in

```
obj1['ádd':'usa','phone':121]
obj2['ádd':'cal','phone':143]
```

and so. on.

Here I want to print all obj's address and pass to HTML id element.

I have done this way but it is print the only the first value but in console printing all values.

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  console.log(results[i].add);
  var jjj=(results[i].add);

  document.getElementById('target_2').innerHTML=jjj;
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't understand what `['ádd':'usa','phone':121] obj2['ádd':'cal','phone':143]` is supposed to mean. This is not valid JS. Did you mean `{'ádd':'usa','phone':121}`?

Comment: Looks like you need to understand Arrays and Object Literals.

Comment: Can you please give full json code here?

Comment: What you show is [not JSON, it is a JavaScript Object/Array literal/initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Object_literal_notation_vs_JSON).

Answer (score 4):

You are consistently replacing the innerHTML of `target_2` rather than appending to it. You want to do something like this instead:

```
document.getElementById('target_2').innerHTML+=jjj;
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to append it. it's work like charm.

Answer (score 2):

```
var jjj = '';
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
   console.log(results[i].add);
   jjj += results[i].add;
}
document.getElementById('target_2').innerHTML = jjj;
```